# How do I match the checksum value of a zip folder with the checksum file?

Tags: shell, sha512

I have a zip folder that has been sent through using sha512 and what I would like to do is check the checksum value of that zip file with the checksum value that I have in a separate .sha512 extension file which contains the checksum value.

So far I have done this to check if the checksum value of the zip matches with the checksum value present in the .sha512 file:

```
if [[ file.zip -ne file.sha512 ]]; then
        echo "Checksum values do not match"
        exit -1;
    fi
    log "info" "Checksum values match"
   done
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, you can also use md5sum, sha1sum or sha256sum depends on your hash.

```
if [[ $(sha512sum file.zip | cut -d " " -f 1) -ne $(cat file.sha512) ]]; then
    echo "Checksum values do not match"
    exit -1;
else
    log "info" "Checksum values match"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for md5sum, please see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/md5sum.htm